# Gitlab CI/CD job continue checking out detached head

Tags: gitlab, cicd

It started when actual changes have not updated release server dependant on master git branch. Previously there was git issues with detached head on master, but now they are all fixed:
[image: Git log]

I tried to stop

- docker containers, `docker system prune -a`;
- remove gitlab runner and register new;
- add `GIT_STRATEGY: clone` to gitlab ci config;

and still get

```
Checking out 11ef1eb7 as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
```

Looking inside container via exec shows that code inside is not the same as in branch.
I am not a devops or smth like that but it happened to be my duty to solve this, any advices appreciated.